# Remote website synchronized with git local branch

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In an EC2 AWS instance, I have a remote bare git repository created following:

```
@server:~$ mkdir -p /home/myuser/domain.git && chmod 770 /home/myuser/domain.git && cd /home/myuser/domain.git && git init --bare
```

With a post-receive hook:

```
@server:~$ nano hooks/post-receive
```

The hook script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo git --work-tree=/var/www/domain --git-dir=/home/myuser/domain.git checkout -f
```

It has permission to execute:

```
@server:~$ chmod +x hooks/post-receive
```

I work on a local repo following:

```
@local:~$ 
    git init
    git remote add server server:/home/myuser/domain.git
    git checkout -b www-dev
    git add .
    git commit -am "Initial"
```

However, when I push changes:

```
@local:~$ git push server www-dev
```

The hook fails:

```
remote: fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born
To server:/home/myuser/domain.git
   06709ae..d1d7ead  www-dev -> www-dev
```

And the website is not updated. Why?

I suspect that the problem is caused by the fact that `git checkout -f` is called by the root. But only the root can write in */var/www/domain*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awkward solution, you have to make your first push to the *master* branch:

```
@local:~$ 
    git init
    git remote add server server:/home/myuser/domain.git
    git add .
    git commit -am "Initial"
    git checkout -b www-dev
    git push server master
```

After that you can checkout to another branch:

```
@local:~$ git checkout -b www-dev
```

However there is another problem: it only deploys the `master` branch. The solution to this problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640210/git-post-receive-hook-for-push-to-deploy-only-works-with-master/30640460#30640460).