# Git post-receive hook for push-to-deploy only works with master

Tags: git, githooks

I have a remote bare git repository created following:

```
@server:~$ mkdir -p /home/myuser/domain.git && chmod 770 /home/myuser/domain.git && cd /home/myuser/domain.git && git init --bare
```

With a post-receive hook:

```
@server:~$ nano hooks/post-receive
```

The hook script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/domain --git-dir=/home/myuser/domain.git checkout -f
```

It has permission to execute:

```
@server:~$ chmod +x hooks/post-receive
```

However, it only changes the website when I push to the *master* branch.

Why? The remote *HEAD* is always *master*, even if I push to another branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, it checkout the master branch.

You would need to specify which branch to checkout, depending on the branch which has just been pushed and received.

Here is an [example of a hook with a specific branch checkout](https://coderwall.com/p/oj5smw/git-post-receive-hook-to-checkout-a-specific-branch):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    branch=`echo $ref | cut -d/ -f3`
    GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/local/checkout git checkout -f $branch
done
```

Be sure to *not* [push multiple branches at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14541136/6309), or only the last branch would be checked out.